# Discord Py tuple index out of range

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    @bot.command()
    async def views(self, ctx, *args):
          channel_name = args[0]
          await ctx.send(channel_name)
```

It says that i a tuple but i want to use a var that contain a username for add on a url
`url = "url" + channel_name`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def views(self, ctx, *, channel_name):
    url = "https://example.com/" + channel_name
    await ctx.send(url)
```

Comment: hi bro thx to help but i have to define channel name is the goal of the function